# Nodejs Wait.For not working

Tags: node.js

I have a really annoying issue.  Basically my code works in all other places apart from in this one instance where wait.for doesn't wait for the redis command to finish before moving on.  The scenario is I trying to process an XML file and update records within a redis DB as the XML file is being read.  The part that is breaking is where I'm trying to retrieve a list of customer card numbers within a region before updating the overall customer record and counts.  But it is not waiting.

Here is the code:

```
function processCredit(creditObj)
{
      .....
      console.log('CREDIT CARD=1');
      wait.launchFiber( updateCustomer, cardNumber );
}

function updateCustomer(cardNumber)
{
    var foundCard=0;
    console.log('CREDIT CARD=2');
    var customerIDs = wait.forMethod(redisClient, 'zrange', 'cn:'+cardNumber+':'+stores[siteId]['region'], 0, -1);
    console.log('CREDIT CARD=3 card number='+cardNumber);
    ....
}
```

"CREDIT CARD=3" statement always gets printed at the end of the log file, not directly after "CREDIT CARD=2"

I've used wait.for in many other places throughout my programme and it has always worked.  I don't understand why it doesn't in this case.

Thanks

Comment: i assume you use `wait.forMethod` to write synchronous code? Why not use something like bluebird/async?

Comment: I've tried using async in the past and I preferred wait.for, it has always worked well up to now.